# Why my id and empty path route not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router-dom

My route with id and no path are not working but others are fine.

> ```
> <Route path='/listings:id' Component={ListingDetail} />
> <Route Component={NotFound} />
> ```

These are not working they just show my HOC component not showing requested components under my HOC when I remove "id" from path '/listings:id' and path in `<Route Component={NotFound} />` then they work fine.

For example, if I put on browser it should route to path='/listings:id'

> `"http://localhost:3000/listings/afsdf"`

and for same if I put path that does not exist

> `"http://localhost:3000/ahkdhfsad"`

it should route to `Component={NotFound}`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import About from './containers/About';
import Contact from './containers/Contact';
import Listings from './containers/Listings';
import ListingDetail from './containers/ListingDetail';
import SignIn from './containers/SignIn';
import SignUp from './containers/SignUp';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import Layout from "./hocs/Layout";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' Component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about' Component={About} />
            <Route path='/contact' Component={Contact} />
            <Route path='/listings:id' Component={ListingDetail} />
            <Route path='/listings' Component={Listings} />
            <Route path='/signin' Component={SignIn} />
            <Route path='/signup' Component={SignUp} />
            <Route Component={NotFound} />
          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- Partial path segments are not valid in React-Router v6. The route path `"/listings:id"` will match the literal string value `"/listings:id"`. If you are wanting to match `"/listings/afsdf"` then separate `":id"` into it's own path segment, e.g. `"/listings/:id"`.
- The "not found" route still needs a path. Specify `path="*"` if you want a "catch-all" route.
- Not a breaking issue, but the `Route` component's `Component` prop is only meant to be used in Data routers (*created using `createBrowserRouter`, `createHashRouter`, etc*).

  > IMPORTANT
  >
  > You should only opt into the Component API for data routes via
  > RouterProvider. Using this API on a `<Route>` inside `<Routes>` will
  > de-optimize React's ability to reuse the created element across
  > renders.

  You should instead use the `element` prop and pass the routed content as JSX.

  See [Route: element/Component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent) for more details.

## Solution

- Update route path `path="/listings:id"` to `path="/listings/:id"`.
- Render `NotFound` on path `path="*"`.
- Use the `element` prop and pass components as JSX.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/listings/:id" element={<ListingDetail />} />
          <Route path="/listings" element={<Listings />} />
          <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  );
};
```